# Select elements from a list of lists based on another list of lists

Tags: python

I have two lists of lists that will always have the same lengths.

```
l1 = [[0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 0, 0]]
l2 = [[0, (1, 'a', 'b'), (1, 'a', 'b'), (1, 'a', 'b'), 0, (3, 'x', 'y'), 0], [0, (2, 'c', 'd'), 0, 0, 0], [0, (3, 'e', 'f'), 0, 0, 0]]
```

What I want is to return the nonzero elements of `l2` only if the quantity of identical elements much the sequence of` 1-2s from l1 (or just 1s). In this case for example, I would like it to return just

```
out = [[(1, 'a', 'b'), (1, 'a', 'b'), (1, 'a', 'b')], [(2, 'c', 'd')], []]
```

because there are three identical tuples and a sequence of `1, 2, 2`, while for `(3, 'e', 'f')`, there is only on but there is a sequence of `1, 2` (so it should have been `(3, 'e', 'f'), (3, 'e', 'f')` instead in `l2`.

What I have been trying to do is use `collections.Counter` to count the occurrences of nonzero elements, but when counting `1` and `2`s it does not differentiate between sequences, so I cannot do a comparison:

```
for x, y in zip(l1, l2):
    print(Counter(x), Counter(y))
```

returns

```
Counter({2: 3, 0: 2, 1: 2}) Counter({0: 3, (1, 'a', 'b'): 3, (3, 'x', 'y'): 1})
Counter({0: 4, 1: 1}) Counter({0: 3, (2, 'c', 'd'): 2})
Counter({0: 5}) Counter({0: 4, (3, 'e', 'f'): 1})
```

There is no way to no what the count of `1` and `2` correspond to.

Any help on how to go about doing this?

Some input-expected output examples:

```
l1 = [[0, 1, 2, 0], [0, 1]]
l2 = [[0, (1, 'a', 'b'), (1, 'a', 'b'), 0], [(2, 'a', 'b'), (2, 'a', 'b')]]
out = [[(1, 'a', 'b'), (1, 'a', 'b')], []]

l1 = [[2, 2, 2], [1, 2]]
l2 = [[(1, 'a', 'b'), (1, 'a', 'b'), (1, 'a', 'b')], [(2, 'a', 'b'), (2, 'a', 'b')]]
out = [[(1, 'a', 'b'), (1, 'a', 'b'), (1, 'a', 'b')], [(2, 'a', 'b'), (2, 'a', 'b')]]

l1 = [[0, 1], [0, 0]]
l2 = [[0, (3, 'x', 'y')], [0, 0]]
out = [[(3, 'x', 'y')], []]
```

Comment: The condition is extremely confusing IMO, I suggest you provide a few simple examples of input and expected output

Comment: in the *out = [[(1,'a','b'), (1,'a','b'), (1,'a','b')], [(2,'c','d'), []]* there are four open brackets but only three closed brackets, I'm confused

Comment: an example with a `(3,x,y)` out would be good

Comment: In first output by what logic. there is empty [] in the last.

Comment: @quickhaze `it should have been (3,'e','f'),(3, 'e','f') instead` all consecutive non-zeros in l1 must have the same tuple in corresponding l2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to find run lengths in your lists. One way to do that is to step through the list and turn a flag on or off when you come to a run boundary. This is a common trick in numpy, where you can mask, diff and sum, but it's not too bad with vanilla python either.

You can label runs by using whatever marker you want. For example, you can label with the run length and start element. In this particular case, that will allow you to compare matching elements directly:

```
def label_runs(lst, zero=0, marker=lambda s, n: (s, n)):
    marks = [0] * len(lst)
    start = -1
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if lst[i] == zero and start >= 0:
            n = i - start
            marks[start:i] = [marker(start, n)] * n
            start = -1
        elif lst[i] != zero and start < 0:
            start = i
    if start >= 0:
        n = len(lst) - start
        marks[start:] = [marker(start, n)] * n
    return marks
```

Now you have a function that does the following:

```
>>> label_runs(l1[0])
[0, (1, 3), (1, 3), (1, 3), 0, (5, 2), (5, 2)]
>>> label_runs(l2[0])
[0, (1, 3), (1, 3), (1, 3), 0, (5, 1), 0]
```

The reason for marking with the start and length instead of just the length is to avoid something like this:

```
>>> label_runs_nostart([0, 1, 2, 2, 0])
[0, 3, 3, 3, 0]
>>> label_runs_nostart([(1, 'a', 'b'), (1, 'a', 'b'), (1, 'a', 'b'), 0, 0])
[3, 3, 3, 0, 0]
```

A direct comparison of such a pathological case would falsely grab the last pair of `(1, 'a', 'b')` if you used direct matching. With the start as an additional check, though, you can trivially take the corresponding elements of each label list and use them to filter the second array where they match:

```
[[x for e1, e2, x in zip(label_runs(i1), label_runs(i2), i2) if x !=0 and e1 == e2] for i1, i2 in zip(l1, l2)]
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution and the explanation!